# TabBarController with NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with 3 tabs set up in my storyboard.  I want to have each tab have its own navigation controller.  However, I don't want to embed each one in a nav controller, cluttering the storyboard and then having to style the navigation each time.  Is there any way to do this programatically?  In other words each time a tab is tapped, the resulting view controller will be set as the root of one existing navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to 'set' the rootViewController every time, but you can do 3 navigationControllers in your storyBoard and build a subclass of UINavigationController. That way you don't have to set it every time. Subclassing UINavigationController has become possible since iOS 6 (See documentation):

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and makes it easier for the user to navigate that content. You generally use this class as-is but in iOS 6 and later you may subclass to customize the class behavior.